# Communicating between DialogFragment and FragmentActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

Being new to Android Dev, I'm having a hard time connecting the dots. I often get stuck on how specific id's can be reached from different fragments, activities, classes - whichever.

For instance.

I have a `DialogFragment` that contains an `EditText` field. I want to add text to that field and on click send that string to a `ListView` in the parent `FragmentActivity`.

Here's the code for the `FragmentActivity` where the `ListView` is.

```
public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AddSiteDialog.AddSiteClick {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_site);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });

    ListView siteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.siteList);


}

public void showDialog() {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new AddSiteDialog();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");

}

public void onSignIn(DialogFragment dialog) {

}

}
```

Here's the `DialogFragment` where the `EditText` lives

```
public class AddSiteDialog extends DialogFragment {

public interface AddSiteClick {
    public void onSignIn(DialogFragment dialog);
}
AddSiteClick addSiteClick;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Rect displayRectangle = new Rect();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();

    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayRectangle);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View view;
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    view.setMinimumWidth((int) (displayRectangle.width() * 0.95f));
    view.setMinimumHeight((int) (displayRectangle.height() * 0.88f));

    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.siteEditText);

    editText.setHint("Enter URL");

    editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setCursorVisible(true);
            editText.setHint("");
           }
    });

    ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addSiteClick.onSignIn(AddSiteDialog.this);
        }
    });

    ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDialog().dismiss();

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

A good explanation of how things communicate to each other would be a great help. Code examples for how this specific task would work together would be great too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, the activity doesn't need to know anything specific about the way the Fragment is implemented. For that reason, the way that fragments/activities communicate is via interfaces and the Fragment's public methods. All of that is covered in [this section of the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

In a nutshell, you would define an interface in your dialog with a single method (e.g. onUserDataEntered) and implement it on the Activity. When the user clicks on the button in the dialog, invoke `onUserDataEntered(theData)`.